# Does prolog have a spread/splat/*args operator?

Tags: prolog, variadic-functions, splat

In many procedural languages *(such as python)*, I can "unpack" a list and use it as arguments for a function. For example...

```
def print_sum(a, b, c):
  sum = a + b + c
  print("The sum is %d" % sum)

print_sum(*[5, 2, 1])
```

This code will print: "`The sum is 8`"

Here is the [documentation for this language feature](https://docs.python.org/dev/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

#### Does prolog have a similar feature?

Is there a way to replicate this argument-unpacking behaviour in Prolog?

For example, I'd like to unpack a list variable before passing it into [call](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=call/2).

Could I write a predicate like this?

```
assert_true(Predicate, with_args([Input])) :-
  call(Predicate, Input).

% Where `Input` is somehow unpacked before being passed into `call`.
```

...That I could then query with

```
?- assert_true(reverse, with_args([ [1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1] ])).
% Should be true, currently fails.

?- assert_true(succ, with_args([ 2, 3 ]).
% Should be true, currently fails.

?- assert_true(succ, with_args([ 2, 4 ]).
% Should be false, currently fails.
```

#### Notes

- You may think that this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It *could* be, but don't get discouraged. It'd be *ideal* to receive an answer for *just* my question title.
- You may tell me that I'm approaching the problem poorly. I know your intentions are good, but this kind of advice won't help to answer the question. Please refer to the above point.
- Perhaps I'm approaching *Prolog* in too much of a procedural mindset. If this is the case, then what mindset would help me to solve the problem?
- I'm using SWI-Prolog.

Comment: You have probably noticed yourself that `call(foo, a, b)` is the same as `call(foo(a, b))` and `call(foo(a), b)`. This is why a call like `include(>(2), [1,2,3,4], R)` works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prolog predicate with variable number of arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20777400/prolog-predicate-with-variable-number-of-arguments)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: it is too easy, using unification and pattern matching, to get the elements of a list or the arguments of any term, if you know its shape. In other words:

```
sum_of_three(X, Y, Z, Sum) :- Sum is X+Y+Z.

?- List = [5, 2, 1],
   List = [X, Y, Z], % or List = [X, Y, Z|_] if the list might be longer
   sum_of_three(X, Y, Z, Sum).
```

For example, if you have command line arguments, and you are interested only in the first two command line arguments, it is easy to get them like this:

```
current_prolog_flag(argv, [First, Second|_])
```

Many standard predicates take lists as arguments. For example, any predicate that needs a number of options, as `open/3` and `open/4`. Such a pair could be implemented as follows:

```
open(SrcDest, Mode, Stream) :-
    open(SrcDest, Mode, Stream, []).

open(SrcDest, Mode, Stream, Options) :-
    % get the relevant options and open the file
```

Here getting the relevant options can be done with a library like [library(option)](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=option), which can be used for example like this:

```
?- option(bar(X), [foo(1), bar(2), baz(3)]).
X = 2.
```

So this is how you can pass named arguments.

Another thing that was not mentioned in the [answer by @false](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41439164/1812457): in Prolog, you can do things like this:

```
Goal = reverse(X, Y), X = [a,b,c], Y = [c,b,a]
```

and at some later point:

```
call(Goal)
```

or even

```
Goal
```

To put it differently, I don't see the point in passing the arguments as a list, instead of just passing the goal as a term. At what point are the arguments a list, and why are they packed into a list?

To put it differently: given how `call` works, there is usually no need for unpacking a list `[X, Y, Z]` to a conjunction `X, Y, Z` that you can then use as an argument list. As in the comment to your question, these are all fine:

```
call(reverse, [a,b,c], [c,b,a])
```

and

```
call(reverse([a,b,c]), [c,b,a])
```

and

```
call(reverse([a,b,c], [c,b,a]))
```

The last one is the same as

```
Goal = reverse([a,b,c], [c,b,a]), Goal
```

This is why you can do something like this:

```
?- maplist(=(X), [Y, Z]).
X = Y, Y = Z.
```

instead of writing:

```
?- maplist(=, [X,X], [Y, Z]).
X = Y, Y = Z.
```

Answer (score 6):

The built-in `(=..)/2` (univ) serves this purpose. E.g.

```
?- G =.. [g, 1, 2, 3].
   G = g(1,2,3).

?- g(1,2,3) =.. Xs.
   Xs = [g,1,2,3].
```

However, note that many uses of `(=..)/2` where the number of arguments is fixed can be replaced by `call/2`...`call/8`.

Comment: This might be exactly what I need. I'll poke around with it and get back if I can use it. Thank you.

Comment: What about the receiving side? How would one go about that? What the legal way to write `my_first(First, *Rest):- nth1(1, Rest, First).`?

Comment: @pkoch the same: `my_first( First, Term ) :- Term =.. [_Functor | Args], nth1(1, Args, First).`, then `?- my_first( First, g(a,b,c,d) ).` ==> `First = a.`.

Comment: That's not really what I'm looking for. How can you, without declaring a relation per arity, make all these calls behave the same? `my_first(First, a)`, `my_first(First, a, b)`, `my_first(First, a, b, c)`, `my_first(First, a, b, c, d)` I know this is not standard practice, but I'm interested in the language faculties, not the style.

Comment: @pkoch for that you'd need to treat all those calls as data. with my definition you'd have to call `my_first( First, my_first( First, a, b, c, d, ...))`. (and FYI there's no notifications if you don't use the @, usually). if a relation is not defined, there's no relation to invoke, of whatever arity. and the only way to define a relation is to define a predicate, with the associated arguments, i.e. arity. you could define all the sub-clauses programmatically though, with `asserta` / `assertz`.